# how to remove the right click menu in swf file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

how to remove the right click menu in swf file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide default options in right click context menu in flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576472/hide-default-options-in-right-click-context-menu-in-flex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576472/hide-default-options-in-right-click-context-menu-in-flex).